# can not set a formula in specific cell

Tags: vba

I trying to put a formula in my spreadsheet this formula works very well when i simply copy & paste in excel but when I try to create a macro for this some error occurs I cant understand what is the reason as it seems everything correct in my macro.
I am using below code-

```
Sub putformula()

range("K4").formula="=IF(ISBLANK($M4);"";IF($M4<=15;ABS($E4)*$K$3;""))"

range("L4").formula="=IF(ISBLANK($M4);"";IF($M4>31;"";IF($M4>15;ABS($E4)*$L$3;"")))"

range("M4").formula="=IF(OR($O4="ABS-Journal";$C4="ABS-Journal");"";IF(ISBLANK($D4);"";IF($C4=$O4;"";IF(MONTH($A4)=MONTH($M$3);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Invoice";$C4;1));$N4-$A4;$A4-$N4);""))))"

range("N4").formula="=IF(ISBLANK($B4);$N3;$A4)"

range("O4").formula="=IF(ISBLANK($B3);$O3;IF(ISBLANK($B3);"";$C4))"


End Sub
```

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error ???

Comment: And also you need to escape the " if you want to use it example: in Excel: "blabla" in VBA "" blabla""

Comment: When you enter formula in VBA, you need to wrote them with English separators and names, whatever your regional settings are. If you want to use your language settings, you need to use the `Range.FormulaLocal` property.

Comment: You need to double up `"` for anything inside a string. **M4:** `"=IF(OR($O4=""ABS-Journal"",$C4=""ABS-Journal""),"""",IF(ISBLANK($D4),"""",IF($C4=$O4,"""",IF(MONTH($A4)=MONTH($M$3),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Invoice"",$C4,1)),$N4-$A4,$A4-$N4),""""))))"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Range("K4").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M4),"" "",IF($M4<=15,ABS($E4)*$K$3,""""))"
```

You are also using `";"` instead of `","` .

The problem is you have to build a string and you were doing it wrong.

Try to understand and make the changes for every other range.

Comment: To me, you are making it more unreadable. `"=IF(ISBLANK($M4),""  "",IF($M4<=15,ABS($E4)*$K$3,""""))"` 2 consecutive double quote should be used here, since you are not concatenating variables.

Comment: So you are saying above will work without the ampersand ?

Comment: You are right Patrick I was confused I though I had to use `&` to concatenate two strings.

Comment: You have to use `&` to concatenate, but here you don't need to concatenate anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply

Comment: thats working but in cell M4 an compile error saying Expected: end of statement" is occuring & sring "ABS" is highlightd with red color

Comment: I have added some more conditions in my formula in cell "M4" and its working also but the problem is formula is very long in length and when I put this in VBA project window text are overlapping

Comment: and I can't see that.
I used ( _) to break the line but in this way I am getting error 
(Copiler Error : Expected:end of  statement)
Pls tell me the way to break code line, thanks in advance for help